# Корректно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Поэтому Вы правильно сформулировали вопрос – есть и риски, но есть и шансы.

И также здесь:

А ведь роль интеллигенции во все времена была другой – предлагать альтернативы, исключать интеллектуальный застой, давать свежие идеи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом предложении желательно тире, которое обозначает  взаимную обусловленность предложений, не уточняя ее конкретный  характер (пояснение или причинно-следственная связь).

Во втором предложении тире обязательно, это  несогласованное определение со значением пояснения, выраженное инфинитивом.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором все правильно.

Первое предложение не является цельным, чисто разговорное, смысл какой-то "разорванный". Тире так тире...

Comment: Да, согласен с Ниманд. Первое предложение разговорное. Здесь пунктуация до конца не разработана. Решение принимает автор.